# rails syntax "render json: @products"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've been using rails in windows for some time, and i've decided to try it on linux recently. So i've been setting everything up, but now the project i had created on windows doesn't run properly on ubuntu: it fails to interpet the following syntax:

```
render json: @products
```

Producing the following error:

```
/home/dcastro/workspace/teste/app/controllers/products_controller.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
  format.json { render json: @products }
                            ^
/home/dcastro/workspace/teste/app/controllers/products_controller.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
  format.json { render json: @product }
```

And only works if i change it to:

```
render :json => @products
```

At first i thought it was because i was using an older version of ruby (namely, 1.8.7). So i installed 1.9.2p290, but that didn't work.

If it matters, i'm using rails 3.1.0 and ubuntu 11.04.

Does anyone know what's causing this? And how can i fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try old syntax `render :json => @products`?

Comment: i did, and i pointed that out in my post.

Comment: I found out what was wrong: even though I installed 1.9.2, the server was being run on 1.8. So I uninstalled ruby1.8 and created a symlink for ruby1.9.2 named "ruby1.8", tricking the server into running on ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 2):

`{ foo: 'bar' }` is the new hash literal syntax, introduced in Ruby 1.9 (not sure which release). So, it should (and does, on my system) work with Ruby 1.9.2p290.

Answer (score 1):

The following is correct!

```
render :json => @products
```

If you setup a `as_json` class method in your Product model, whatever you place in that hash will be included in the response at your JSON endpoint.

As per the official 3.1 rails guide, [this is the correct syntax](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render).